# Generate Hexadecimal value using Groovy

Tags: groovy, hex, soapui

I am trying to generate Hexadecimal value using Groovy but sometimes it generate Incorrect HEX value.

Groovy Code :

```
def randomuserserial = Long.toUnsignedString(new Random().nextLong(), 16).toUpperCase()
log.info randomuserserial
```

e.g : It generates 'C9786B0146A68638' and when i converted into decimal error displayed 'Hex number must be smaller then 7fffffffffffffff'

Comment: provide the code where you converting hex back to long.

Comment: using online converter. http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

but this converter accepts only hex numbers lower then `7fffffffffffffff`

it means it accepts only positive decimal numbers or zero

you can use abs() method to convert negative number to positive before converting to hex string

```
Long.toUnsignedString(new Random().nextLong().abs(), 16).toUpperCase()
```

on other hand the hex parser in java/groovy could parse numbers larger then `7fffffffffffffff`:

```
def s='C9786B0146A68638'
def i = Long.parseUnsignedLong(s, 16)
println i
```

Comment: so that means now only those HEX value is generated which has positive decimals after conversion.